# Creating Min Heap from STL Priority Queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue, min-heap

I am creating a min heap from stl priority queue. Here is my class which I am using.

```
class Plane
{
  private :
    int id ;
    int fuel ;
 public:
    Plane():id(0), fuel(0){}
    Plane(const int _id, const int _fuel):id(_id), fuel(_fuel) {}

    bool operator > (const Plane &obj)
    {
        return ( this->fuel > obj.fuel ? true : false ) ;
    }
```

} ;

In main I instantiate an object thus.

```
 priority_queue<Plane*, vector<Plane*>, Plane> pq1 ;
 pq1.push(new Plane(0, 0)) ;
```

I am getting an error from `xutility` which I am unable to understand.

> d:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(674): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

Any help to its solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The third template parameter must be a binary functor taking teo `Plane*`. Your `Plane` class does not provide that.

You need something of the form

```
struct CompPlanePtrs
{
  bool operator()(const Plane* lhs, const Plane* rhs) const {
    return lhs->fuel > rhs->fuel ;
  }
};
```

Comment: Can't i do that with operator >?. making it a friend?
It doesnt get right with operator() either.

Comment: @Sasha the problem is that you need to compare *pointers* to `Planes`, not `Planes`. You cannot overload `operator>` for pointers.

Answer (score 12):

If you drop the use of pointers (which are overkill for your simple structures), then you can use [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) from the header `functional`:

```
std::priority_queue<Plane, std::vector<Plane>, std::greater<Plane> > pq1;
pq1.push(Plane(0, 0));
```

Currently, you are feeding `Plane` as the comparison type. That won't work since the comparison type must be a type of function object, i.e. it must have an `operator()` that does the comparison. `Plane` doesn't have such a member (and adding it just for this purpose would be a bad idea).

`std::greater` has the appropriate method, implemented in terms of your `operator>`. However, it doesn't work with pointers, because then it uses a pointer comparison (based on memory addresses).

Btw., note that your comparison function can be expressed more succinctly as

```
bool operator>(const Plane &other)
{
    return fuel > other.fuel;
}
```

Comment: Okay but for an upvote from me this answer needs an explanation of why the element type is an unsuitable comparator type and consequently why the OP's original code did not compile. :-)

Comment: It works fine, but I cannot get the reason behind that, as @Lightness Races in Orbit mentions.

Comment: @larsmans how would it know that it has to order according to my fuel?

Comment: `std::greater` will invoke your `operator>`. It just knows to do that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: too bad you didn't catch the gravest error of all: `std::greater` would do a pointer comparison. Changed the answer, again.

Comment: @larsmans But I have to create a dynamic object each at each time unit. I cannot simply drop the pointers.

Comment: @Sasha: then the other answer is what you need. You can't overload `operator>` on pointers, because it's already defined.